# Property does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)

Tags: angular, typescript

So here is my code and I have this error and I don't understand why.
I need some help here... I don't know why is this happening :
Property does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339) at :`return users.find(u => u.userName === user.userName && u.password === user.password)` on u.userName and u.password . PLease help .

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor() { }

  authUser(user: any) {
    let users : string[] = [];
    if(localStorage.getItem('Users')) {
      users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Users') || '{}');
    }
    return users.find(u => u.userName === user.userName && u.password === user.password)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change like below to solve:

> let users : any[] = [];

main reason is the string[] has no property like

userName or password

suggestion: there are too much logical gap in **authUser** function, so you should write the function to handle the logic more preciously.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing  `let users : string[] = [];`
to

```
let users;
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Like establishen in other answer, you have declared it as a string array, which has no such properties like password and username. What you should do, as we are coding with Typescript, create interfaces (my preference) and type your data. Just dummy example here:

```
export interface MyInterface {
  userName: string;
  password: string;
}
```

and the function:

```
authUser(user: MyInterface) {
  let users : MyInterface[] = [];
  users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Users')) || [];
  return users.find(u => u.userName === user.userName && u.password === user.password)
}
```

Also check the function, you can just do:

```
users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Users')) || [];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the error is that an "object" is not iterable like and a array, so if Users is not set in local storage, you should do something like:

```
users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Users') || '[]');
```

Note the difference between '{}' and '[]' inside JSON.parse

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error exists because the typing is not consistent across your code.

```
let users : string[] = []; // type is string[]
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Users') || '{}'); // type is unknown | object
```

The type of the `let users` is not compatible with the type returned by `JSON.parse(...)`.

- `let users` needs to be typed to `{ userName: any, password: any}[]`;
- `JSON.parse(...)` should be updated to `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Users')) || []`;

I would recoment to create an interface `User` like so:

```
export interface User {
  userName: any;
  password: any;
}
```

And updating your service to:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor() { }

  authUser(user: User) {
    let users : User[] = [];
    if(localStorage.getItem('Users')) {
      users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Users') || '[]');
    }
    return users.find((u: User) => u.userName === user.userName && u.password === user.password)
  }
}
```